# Is there a EmptyStringCheckStrategy in MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I would like to map from DTO to Entity. For that I use `MapStruct`. I would like to perform all String fields both on null check and emptycheck like:

`if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {...}`  or much better  if

`(StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {...}`

I have seen that in MapperConfig we can configure the null check with:

```
nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS
```

Is it possible to configure the empty check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible. I remember seeing an issue in the MapStruct issue tracker about something similar. Perhaps [mapstruct/mapstruct#879](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/879).

One way to do it though is to add a cust `hasName()` method on your object that would then use `StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can define a method:

```java
default String toString(String in) {
   if ( in != null && !in.isEmpty() {
       return in;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this actually works?

Comment: I did not check this on the recent code base. But, normally it should. Although the approach of @Filip is better.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was my mistake :)

Comment: But I don't agree that the accepted answer is better since DTO classes should not have any business logics(even including util logics).